# onEdit event object active user is returning my email address instead of the user doing the edit

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet with an installed trigger / app script.  The script uses the event object (I call it e) to do various things.  One thing I am trying is to get the email address of the user who is doing the editing of the Google sheets.  So, if the event object is e, the e.user should return the user id / email address of the person logged into the Google sheet and performing the action.  But, what it does instead do is return MY email address.  I'm guessing the e.user id is the id of the user the app script is running under.  Can any Google engineers chime in?  How can I get the user id of the person doing the editing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, wow, I finally got this working, and that was a weird one.  So, if the trigger is installable as opposed to simple, and the users doing the editing belong to my same domain, then the e.user should work.  It wasn't.  What I eventually figured out is when one of the shared collaborators opens up the apps script editor from the container, for some reason, everything started working.  So, I'm now able to get the user id's and emails from all the users in my domain when they perform an action.  It seems like this is a bug.  I dunno.  But it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the User's Email with `e.user.getEmail()`;

Here's the documentation comment:

getEmail()

Gets the user's email address, if available. If security policies do not allow access to the user's email address, this method returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.

Comment: Yeah, e.user will return the email address by default.  Using the getEmail() function is redundant.  Anyways, I tried it both ways before and it keeps returning MY user id / email instead of the person performing the Google Sheets edit.  I'm guessing this is due to the apps script being deployed under my account--as an aside, the scripts are not deployed as a web app.  So, I'm still wondering, how does one get the user id of the person performing the edit?  I've tried several different users, some from the same GSuite domain as me, and from external accounts, and the e.user keeps returning me.